# How do I get my React like button to increment when not liked, and then decrement when liked?

Tags: reactjs, button, components, state

The state variable `likes` just continues to increment. I thought I have my `onSelect` function alternating the boolean value of `liked`, but apparently not.

Here's the error:

```
Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls 
setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested
 updates to prevent infinite loops.
```

Here's App.js:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import LikeButton from './components/LikeButton';

function App() {
  const [likes, updateLikes] = useState(23);
  const [liked, updateLiked] = useState(false);

  return (
    <LikeButton 
    secret='like-button'
    numLikes={likes}
    liked={liked}
    // status={liked}
    onSelect={function clickLike(liked) { //This function is happening, but the else block
      // never fires.
      if (liked) {
        updateLikes(likes + 1);
       } else { updateLikes(likes - 1)
       };
      updateLiked(!liked);
      }
    }
    />
    // onClick function here, or in LikeButton.js?
  );
}

export default App;
```

And here's LikeButton.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { FaThumbsUp } from 'react-icons/fa';

export default function LikeButton({secret, liked, numLikes, onSelect}) {
    return (
      <>
        <FaThumbsUp />
        <div key={secret} liked={liked} onClick={onSelect(liked)}>Like Button</div>
        <p>{numLikes}</p>
      </>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

You invoke your `onClick` callback immediately, which updates state in the parent.

```
import React from 'react';
import { FaThumbsUp } from 'react-icons/fa';

export default function LikeButton({secret, liked, numLikes, onSelect}) {
    return (
      <>
        <FaThumbsUp />
        <div
          key={secret}
          liked={liked}
          onClick={onSelect(liked)} // invoked right away
        >
          Like Button
        </div>
        <p>{numLikes}</p>
      </>
    );
}
```

## Solution

Make it an anonymous inner function.

```
import React from 'react';
import { FaThumbsUp } from 'react-icons/fa';

export default function LikeButton({secret, liked, numLikes, onSelect}) {
    return (
      <>
        <FaThumbsUp />
        <div
          key={secret}
          liked={liked}
          onClick={() => onSelect(liked)} // invoked when clicked
        >
          Like Button
        </div>
        <p>{numLikes}</p>
      </>
    );
}
```

### Suggestion

You should also really use functional state updates when the next state values *depend* on current state values, i.e. when incrementing/decrementing counts or toggling a boolean. I also suggest to move the `updateLikes` into an `useEffect` hook to react to `liked` being toggled. This may make the logic about incrementing/decrementing a little clearer.

```
function App() {
  const [likes, updateLikes] = useState(23);
  const [liked, updateLiked] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    updateLikes(likes => likes + (liked ? 1 : -1));
  }, [liked]);

  return (
    <LikeButton 
      secret='like-button'
      numLikes={likes}
      liked={liked}
      // status={liked}
      onSelect={function clickLike(liked) {
        updateLiked(liked => !liked);
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I just read about useEffect(). My understanding is this: It is called after a rerender. So when the onClick function is called, it changes `liked`, the state boolean variable, which rerenders, so that useEffect() is called, which updates `likes`, the other state variable, causing another rerender which shows the correct number of likes. Is that right?